# Splitting link list

Tags: c++, list, hyperlink

I am trying to split a linked list of int at a certain value with the values greater than and less than in their own lists. My code currently seg faults when it tries ptr2->data = original->data;

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

struct node{
 int data;
 node * link;
};



void build_list(node* & head);  
void show_list(const node* head);
int size(const node* head);


 void remove_repeats(node*& head);
 void split_list(const node* original, node*& lesser, 
    node*& greater,int split_value);


int main(){
int start, stop;
int split;
node* head = NULL;
node *lesser;
node * greater;

start = time(NULL);
build_list(head);
stop = time(NULL);
cout<<"Time to build list = "<<stop - start <<"seconds.\n";
start = time(NULL);
show_list(head);
stop = time(NULL);
cout<<"Time to print list = "<<stop - start<<"seconds.\n";
cout<<"Size of the list = "<<size(head)<<endl;
cout<<"Removing repeats" << endl;
remove_repeats(head);
show_list(head);
cout<<"The size of the list is now " << size(head) << endl;
cout<<"Enter value to split list at" << endl;
cin >> split;
split_list(head, lesser, greater, split);
cout<<"The number less than split value" << endl;
show_list(lesser);
cout<<"The numbers greater than splt value" << endl;
show_list(greater);

return 0;
}

// builds a linked list of 2000 random integers, all in the 1 to 500 range
void build_list(node*& head){
 node* cursor;
 head = new node;
 head->data = rand()%500 + 1;
 cursor = head;
 for(int i = 0; i < 2000; ++i){
cursor->link = new node;
    cursor = cursor->link;
    cursor->data = rand()%500 + 1;
 }
 cursor->link = NULL;
}

// outputs the contents of a linked list to the screen
void show_list(const node* head){
  const node * cursor = head;
  while(cursor !=  NULL){
cout<<cursor->data<<"  ";
cursor = cursor->link;
  }
 cout<<endl;
}

// returns the number of nodes in a linked list
int size(const node* head){
const node* cursor = head;
int count = 0;
while(cursor != NULL){
    count++;
    cursor = cursor->link;
}
return count;
}

void remove_repeats(node*& head)
{
node *cur, *next, *prev;

cur = head;

while(cur != NULL){
       next = cur->link;
       prev = cur;
            while(next != NULL){
               if(next->data == cur->data){
                  prev->link = next->link;
                  delete next;
                  next = prev->link;
               }
               else{
                  prev = next;
                  next = next->link;
               }
            }
       cur = cur->link;
    }
}

void split_list(const node* original, node*& lesser, node*& greater, int split_value){

    node* ptr1;
    node* ptr2;
    ptr1 = lesser;
    ptr2 = greater;

        for(original; original != NULL; original = original->link){

                if(original->data < split_value){
           ptr1->data = original->data;
           ptr1->link = new node;
           ptr1 = ptr1->link;
                }
        else if(original->data > split_value){
               ptr2->data = original->data;
                   ptr2->link = new node;
                   ptr2 = ptr2->link;

                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Anytime you're talking about splitting or merging *existing* linked lists. lose the idea of (a) allocating new nodes, or (b) copy *member* data. Linked list algorithms are about *pointer management*. Much time spent on the end of a pencil drawing boxes and arrows on a piece of paper will eventually gel that. In short, the words `new node;` and `...->data = ...` should be unnecessary in your split function unless you're **copying** the list as well as splitting it.

Comment: I am fist building a list of 2000 integers. Then I am removing all duplicate integers. Next, I am entering in a value to split that reduced list into tow other lists, one with values less than the split value then one with values greater than the split value.

Comment: Would it be ok to just build the list *sorted* as you create it. That would make duplicate removal and splitting trivial.

Comment: That would make sense however it is the assignment to just remove duplicates then split the list.

Comment: @sa044512 Did you test your removal of the duplicate values separately to make sure there are *no* bugs in that routine.  And I mean *NO* bugs?  For example, a simple main() program that prints the list successfully *after* you've removed the duplicates?  If not, then you need to do that first.

Comment: Yes I did and yes it works with no bugs.

Comment: @sa044512 Then why did you post that code to remove the duplicates?  Just post the code that builds the linked list, the code to split the list, and a simple main() function that builds and then splits the list.  The data can be simple non-duplicate items.

Answer (score 1):

Your function faults because you're dereferencing NULL or indeterminate pointers, and it is fairly easy to see where:

Given you're passing two pointers by-reference for the lower and upper lists to eventually populate, this:

```
void split_list(const node* original, node*& lesser, node*& greater, int split_value){

    node* ptr1;
    node* ptr2;
    ptr1 = lesser;  // lesser is NULL or indeterminate, so is ptr1
    ptr2 = greater; // greater is NULL or indeterminate, so is ptr2

    for(original; original != NULL; original = original->link){

        if(original->data < split_value){
            ptr1->data = original->data; // ptr1 still bad. boom
            ptr1->link = new node;
            ptr1 = ptr1->link;
        }
        else if(original->data > split_value){
            ptr2->data = original->data; // ptr2 still bad, boom
            ptr2->link = new node;
            ptr2 = ptr2->link;
        }
    }
}
```

This conclusion is supported by looking at the caller, where the two pointers passed in are:

```
node *lesser;
node * greater;
```

I.e. indeterminate. and never changed before invoking the split function.

I think you're reading too much into this assignment. As you've put it, there is no need to make a **copy** of the original list. Just pass the head pointer in by-reference as well, and pull nodes from that list, populating the lower and upper lists respectively. The following code is one such way to do that, using a technique called *forward chaining* that utilizes a pointer-to-pointer always containing the address where to store the next node pointer of a list:

```
void split_list(node *& head, node *& lhs, node *& rhs, int value)
{
    node **pplhs = &lhs;
    node **pprhs = &rhs;

    for (;head; head = head->link)
    {
        node **& pp = (head->data < value) ? pplhs : pprhs;
        *pp = head;
        pp = &(*pp)->link;
    }
    *pplhs = *pprhs = nullptr;
}
```

When finished, the original list is empty (`head` will be NULL) and the two other lists have been setup per the split value test. No new nodes were created; the nodes were taken *from* the original list, leaving it empty.

Best of luck